# java.lang.RuntimeException : Unable to start activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent, android-activity

***emphasized text***

```
04-09 02:16:18.029: E/AndroidRuntime(6560): FATAL EXCEPTION: main<br>
04-09 02:16:18.029: E/AndroidRuntime(6560): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.game.lutung/com.game.lutung.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
<br>04-09 02:16:18.029: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
<br>04-09 02:16:18.029: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
<br>04-09 02:16:18.029: E/AndroidRuntime(6560): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
<br>04-09 02:16:18.029: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
<br>04-09 02:16:18.029: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
<br>04-09 02:16:18.029: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
<br>04-09 02:16:18.029: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
<br>04-09 02:16:18.029: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
<br>04-09 02:16:18.029: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
<br>04-09 02:16:18.029: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
<br>04-09 02:16:18.029: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
<br>04-09 02:16:18.029: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
<br>04-09 02:16:18.029: E/AndroidRuntime(6560): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
<br>04-09 02:16:18.029: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
<br>04-09 02:16:18.029: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
<br>04-09 02:16:18.029: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
<br>04-09 02:16:18.029: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386)
<br>04-09 02:16:18.029: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
<br>04-09 02:16:18.029: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
<br>04-09 02:16:18.029: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
<br>04-09 02:16:18.029: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
<br>04-09 02:16:18.029: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at com.game.lutung.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
<br>04-09 02:16:18.029: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
<br>04-09 02:16:18.029: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
<br>04-09 02:16:18.029: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     ... 11 more
<br>04-09 02:16:18.029: E/AndroidRuntime(6560): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
<br>04-09 02:16:18.029: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
<br>04-09 02:16:18.029: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
<br>04-09 02:16:18.029: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
<br>04-09 02:16:18.029: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     ... 21 more
<br>04-09 02:16:18.029: E/AndroidRuntime(6560): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
<br>04-09 02:16:18.029: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
<br>04-09 02:16:18.029: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:460)
<br>04-09 02:16:18.029: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:336)
<br>04-09 02:16:18.029: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
<br>04-09 02:16:18.029: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
<br>04-09 02:16:18.029: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
<br>04-09 02:16:18.029: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1951)
<br>04-09 02:16:18.029: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1899)
<br>04-09 02:16:18.029: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:286)
<br>04-09 02:16:18.029: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:173)
<br>04-09 02:16:18.029: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     ... 24 more
```

Code:

```
   package com.game.lutung;

   import java.sql.SQLException;

   import com.game.dbcontroller.DBCreateBahasa;
   import com.game.dbcontroller.DBCreateLevel;
   import com.game.model.Level;
   import com.game.view.Komik;

   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.database.Cursor;
   import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.KeyEvent;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
   import android.view.Window;
   import android.view.WindowManager;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.ImageView;

   public class PilihLevel extends Activity {
     final Context context = this;

     private DBCreateBahasa dbCreateBahasa;
     private DBCreateLevel dbCreateLevel;
     private LutungCreate lutungCreate;
     private LutungSetPosition lutungSetPosition;
private SQLiteDatabase database;

private String jenisBahasa;

private ImageView judul;
private ImageView level1;
private ImageView level2;
private ImageView level3;
private ImageView level4;
private ImageView level5;
private ImageView level6;

private int id_level;
private String level;
private String status;
private String keterangan;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.pilih_level);

    //suara
    Sound.setOST(context);

    //pamanggilan class DBCreateBahasa
    dbCreateBahasa = new DBCreateBahasa(context);
    dbCreateBahasa.open();
    jenisBahasa=dbCreateBahasa.getBahasaTerpilih();

    judul = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.judulLevel);

    //method untuk setting bahasa
    setBahasa();

    //pemanggilan class DBCreateLevel
    dbCreateLevel = new DBCreateLevel(context);
    try {
        dbCreateLevel.open();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    database = openOrCreateDatabase("lutung.db", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

    //pemanggilan class
    lutungCreate = new LutungCreate();
    lutungSetPosition = new LutungSetPosition();

    level1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.level1);
    level2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.level2);
    level3 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.level3);
    level4 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.l4);
    level5 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.level5);
    level6 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.level6);

    //method cek level
    cekLevelInDatabase();

    //tombol untuk level 1
    level1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Sound.setButtonClick(context);
            dbCreateLevel.pilihLevel(1, "digunakan");
            Intent cerita = new Intent(context, Komik.class);
            startActivity(cerita);
        }
    });
}

//method setting bahasa
private void setBahasa() {
    if(jenisBahasa.equals("English")){
        judul.setImageResource(R.drawable.level);
    }/*else if(jenisBahasa.equals("Sunda")){
        judul.setImageResource(R.drawable.level);
    }*/
}

//method cek level
private void cekLevelInDatabase() {
    //query
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM level WHERE keterangan = 'terbuka'", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
        while(true){
            id_level = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id_level"));
            level = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("level"));
            status = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("status"));
            keterangan = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("keterangan"));

            System.out.println("id_level:"+id_level+", level :"+level+", status:"+status+", keterangan:"+keterangan);

            //tombol untuk level 2
            if(id_level == 2){
                level2.setImageResource(R.drawable.level2);
                level2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Sound.setButtonClick(context);
                        dbCreateLevel.pilihLevel(2, "digunakan");
                        Intent cerita = new Intent(context, Komik.class);
                        startActivity(cerita);
                    }
                });
            //tombol untuk level 3
            }else if(id_level == 3){
                level3.setImageResource(R.drawable.level3);
                level3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Sound.setButtonClick(context);
                        dbCreateLevel.pilihLevel(3, "digunakan");
                        Intent cerita = new Intent(context, Komik.class);
                        startActivity(cerita);
                    }
                });
            //tombol untuk level 4
            }else if (id_level == 4){
                level4.setImageResource(R.drawable.level4);
                level4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Sound.setButtonClick(context);
                        dbCreateLevel.pilihLevel(4, "digunakan");
                        Intent cerita = new Intent(context, Komik.class);
                        startActivity(cerita);
                    }
                });
            //tombol untuk level 5
            }else if(id_level == 5){
                level5.setImageResource(R.drawable.level5);
                level5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Sound.setButtonClick(context);
                        dbCreateLevel.pilihLevel(5, "digunakan");
                        Intent cerita = new Intent(context,
                                Komik.class);
                        startActivity(cerita);
                    }
                });
            //tombol untuk level 6
            }else if(id_level == 6){
                level6.setImageResource(R.drawable.level6);
                level6.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Sound.setButtonClick(context);
                        dbCreateLevel.pilihLevel(6, "digunakan");
                        Intent cerita = new Intent(context,
                                Komik.class);
                        startActivity(cerita);
                    }
                });
            }

            if(!cursor.moveToNext())
                break;
        }
    }else{
        System.out.println("data tidak ada");
    }
    cursor.close();
}

//method untuk kembali ke halaman utama
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
        Sound.setOSTMainStop(context);
        Intent home = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(home);
        //dbCreateLevel.close();
        //dbCreateBahasa.close();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

}

Comment: `Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>` Please post `/res/layout/pilih_level`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you look at the stacktrace of the Exception you'll see the root cause:

```
OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
```

That means you are trying to load an image that is too big for the available memory. There is no other solution that to use a smaller image.

**Edit:**

[Here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) is some more information about the handling of large images.

Comment: that means image size?

Comment: If you read the log, an error occurred in the XML file before this. This can not be determined to be the root cause of the issue as it could have been caused by a prior failure, the question is incomplete as stands because it does not provide enough information.

Comment: @MattClark - untrue.  This is the actual causative error, which lead to those appearing *higher* in the *same* fault report.